# Fill blank in table with data from previous row SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with various null fields.

```
ID Value  
1   A
2             
3   
4   B
5
```

Need to transform it to this output table:

```
ID Value  
1   A
2   A          
3   A
4   B
5   B
```

Requirement:
Preview the table before updating. Hence, a select statement with returns the above mentioned output table.

An update query which updates the first table to second table.

Unable to find any select query which shows the table in required format. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: also, what have you tried? SO isn't meant to make stuff for you, SO is for specific questions.

Comment: if all the records were `null` but '4' were 'A' what would be your expected output?

Comment: @HughJones In that case there will be 3 null followed by 2 'A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mysql query that uses a variable to keep track of the most recent non-null value

```
SELECT t1.id, 
(CASE WHEN Value IS NULL
THEN @prevValue
ELSE @prevValue := Value END) Value
FROM myValues t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevValue := NULL) t2
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,value CHAR(1) NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,'A'),
 (2,NULL),
 (3,NULL),
 (4,'B'),
 (5,NULL);

 SELECT x.*
      , MAX(y.value) 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.value IS NOT NULL 
    AND y.id <= x.id 
  GROUP 
     BY x.id;
 +----+-------+--------------+
 | id | value | MAX(y.value) |
 +----+-------+--------------+
 |  1 | A     | A            |
 |  2 | NULL  | A            |
 |  3 | NULL  | A            |
 |  4 | B     | B            |
 |  5 | NULL  | B            |
 +----+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: This query ONLY works if the values in the `value` field are guaranteed to be ascending. This is because you are returning a MAX() value of EVERYTHING where y.id <= x.id. Only works in very specific circumstances

Comment: @JaredGreen I hope the OP hasn't been holding out for 4 years for that little titbit

Comment: Just trying to be a good neighbor for future seekers. I had the same issue and came across this answer. I tried it out for about 20 minutes before really thinking through the logic of the query and realizing why it wasn’t doing what I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Increment')>0
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Increment
END

CREATE TABLE #Increment (
   id           INT      
,  Increment    VARCHAR(10)      
   )

INSERT INTO #Increment (id, Increment)
   SELECT  1, 'A'       UNION
   SELECT  2, NULL      UNION
   SELECT  3, NULL      UNION
   SELECT  4, 'B'       UNION
   SELECT  5, NULL      UNION
   SELECT  6, NULL      UNION
   SELECT  7, 'C'       UNION
   SELECT  8, NULL      UNION
   SELECT  9, NULL      


;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT T1.id, 

               Increment = COALESCE(T1.Increment, (SELECT TOP 1 T2.Increment 
                                      FROM   #Increment T2 
                                      WHERE  T2.id < T1.id  
                                             AND T2.Increment IS NOT NULL 
                                      ORDER  BY id DESC))

         FROM   #Increment T1) 
UPDATE T 
SET    T.Increment = C.Increment 

FROM   #Increment T 
       INNER JOIN cte C 
               ON T.id = C.id 
WHERE  T.Increment IS NULL 

select * from #Increment
```